# Efficient Way to Allow TOC Section Entries to be of Different Fonts

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, tocloft, italic, small-caps

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\itshape}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter with Not All Sections of Italic Font}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section entry in italics default.}

\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\scshape}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section entry to appear in small caps.}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\itshape}

\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section entry displayed once again in italics.}
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC:

[image]

I would like to temporarily change the TOC sectional cursive (italics) font to small caps; and then, return it to italics.

To this end, I inserted `\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\scshape}` immediately previous to the second section entry; and then, inserted the command `\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\itshape}` immediately thereafter. But this does not seem to work.

QUESTION: How may I temporarily change the sectional TOC default font to something else, in this case, to small caps, and then return it to the default?

*Remark* `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\scshape{Subsection entry to appear in small caps.}}` does work, but I am looking for a more automatic way of accomplishing this in the event, say, I had numerous such entries.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the table of contents or list of figures/tables are typesetted in the next formatting run.  This means that changes in the predefined fonts for an entry lines has to be done at the time when the toc or lof/lot file is processed and not when the document text with the section and subsection headers are formatted.

To achieve this LaTeX has defined and uses the commands `\addcontentsline` and `\addtocontents`.

If you want to change some of the predefined fonts, e.g., `\cftsecfont` or `\cftsubsecfont` as in your example, you have to add this redefinitions into the toc file.

In your example put the font change commands in `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` lines and `\protect` all expandable macros inside the moving argument of `\addtocontents`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Chapter with Not All Sections of Italic Font}
\section{Section entry in italics default.}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecfont}{\protect\scshape}}

\section{Section entry to appear in small caps.}
\lipsum[1]

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftsecfont}{\protect\itshape}}

\newpage
\section{Section entry displayed once again in italics.}
\lipsum[1]x
\end{document}
```

For a more general solution - if you want to change the formatting of more toc levels - it is better to collect all toc formatting `\renewcommand` setting macros into a small set of macros.  And these macros are then used inside the `\addtocontents` macro calls.

Inside a document it is best to use only "descriptive" macro names,
which represent the meaning of the following or enclosed portion of text
and hide the implementation.  Therefore it is best to hide low-level
macros like `\addtocontents` and similar macros and introduce
descriptive macros for the document author.  And finally you can move
these macros inside a package.

Applying these two steps you get

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\itshape}

\newcommand{\specialTocFormatting}{%
  \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\scshape}%
  % ... more changes
}

\newcommand{\standardTocFormatting}{%
  \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\itshape}%
  % ... more formatting sett
}

\newcommand{\changeToSpecialTocFormatting}{%
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\specialTocFormatting}}

\newcommand{\changeToStandardTocFormatting}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\standardTocFormatting}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Chapter with Not All Sections of Italic Font}
\section{Section entry in italics default.}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage

\changeToSpecialTocFormatting

\section{Section entry to appear in small caps.}
\lipsum[1]

\changeToStandardTocFormatting

\newpage
\section{Section entry displayed once again in italics.}
\lipsum[1]x
\end{document}
```

When you LaTeX this example two times the .aux file will have the content

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chapter with Not All Sections of Italic Font}{3}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Section entry in italics default.}{3}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\specialTocFormatting }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Section entry to appear in small caps.}{4}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\standardTocFormatting }
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Section entry displayed once again in italics.}{5}{}\protected@file@percent }
```

and the .toc file will have the content

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chapter with Not All Sections of Italic Font}{3}{}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Section entry in italics default.}{3}{}%
\specialTocFormatting 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Section entry to appear in small caps.}{4}{}%
\standardTocFormatting 
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Section entry displayed once again in italics.}{5}{}%
```

and the formatted table of contents looks like

[image]

Comment: When I run your code, I get a chapter number, as well as section numbers for all the sections in the TOC. Would you be able to modify your code so the output resembles the output in the MWE? Thank you. Perhaps you will post your output? Thanks again.

Comment: I have generalized the solution and added a screenshot of the resulting formatting.  If you want to also change the formatting of the section or chapter toc lines, add the necessary font change command to the newly defined two macros.  My solution show a possible principle way how to do this with some simple macros.  Hope this helps.